# Add one object in list nested entity in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I create a repository layer in my app. I don't need all list EntityList. I want add in `Foo.EntityList` 1 object which equals `entityId`, and return foo in notImportant. How can I do this?

I am using EF Core 3.1 - I can't use `Where()` in `Include()`.

How can I realize this contruction in EF Core 3.1?

```
 Foo.Include(c => c.Entity.Where(o => o.Id == entityId)).ThenInclude(o => o.EntityProperty)
```

I thought to do it with `Join()` but I don't know how.

This is the method in my repo:

```
Task<NotIpmortantEntity> FetchNotImportantEntity(int year, Guid foosId, Guid entityId);
{
    var db = Datasource();
    var foo = db.Foo.Where(/???/)   
    var notImportant = NotIpmortantEntity.New(year, Foo);
}
```

Foo has these properties:

```
Foo:
|--Guid FoosId
|--IList<Entity> EntityList
```

And `Entity` has these properties:

```
Entity:
|--Guid EntityId
```

Comment: It looks like you should be adding to db.Entity and then returning db.Foo

Comment: @b166er Like this? 
    var entity = db.Entity.Include(e => e.Everythig).Where(e => e.Id == entityId).ToListAsync(); 
    var foo = db.Foo().Where(e => e.Entity == entity);

Comment: @b166er but it's not the same thing, Foo wiil ind list where entity contains 1 obj, but this list does not exist

Comment: EF Core 3.1 does not support filtered `Include`. EF Core 5 is the first version to support this.

Comment: You will have to use regular `Join`: `var foo = db.Foo.Join(db.Entity, f => f.Id, e => e.FooID, (f,e) => new { f, e }).Where(fe => fe.e.Id == entityId);`. Note you say `Entity` has property `EntityId` but your code has `o.Id`???

Comment: @kartav4ik I think you need to describe the issue in more detail, perhaps we're getting lost in translation. Something like "I have a Foo which contains a list of Entity. I want to insert the list of Entity from the Foo object and then insert the new Foo. I then want to return the new Foo, with the list of new Entity inside the foo object", that's how I understand you issue currently :)

Comment: @NetMage what is o.Id?    
I tried your way. But it's returning Task<f,e>. I want return Foo with 1(!!!) object in EntityList. Filtred collection in ef core 3. How can I to make this?

Comment: @b166er sorry, i have a bad english, to hard difficult to express one's thoughts in another. In short my problem -- I have an entity Foo with list EntityList, I want filtred EntityList in EF core 3.1. so that EntityList contains 1 obj Entity.Id == entityId and return Foo with filtred EntityList to create new obj NotImportant

Comment: No worries, English is my second language as well :D Ok since the issue is around Foo.Include, then I support @NetMage answer (that you can't do this in EF 3.1) that you would need a join in Linq. Alternatively you would need to read from Foo and then from Entity and combine the result.

Comment: @b166er I don't understand how do this. When I make join returned anonimous obj and I can't to create an obj NotImportant